# curl: when is output file created

Tags: curl, rpc

In case one has requested that the curl output be transferred to output.txt, then when exactly is the output file created.

I ask this because of the following issue that I am facing:
1. I give an rpc call which has a lot of data to be retrieved. 
2, After the date is retrieved, i then go and read output.txt to get all the data i need.
3. But some rpc calls take some time for the data to be retrieved (as lot of data), thus I am not sure how long to wait before i go to read output.txt
4. I don't wish to give any random number as it would slow down the code.
5. Now i was thinking if output file is created after all the data is received then it woudl be easy as i just need to check for the existence of output.txt and then go an read. 
But i am not sure if this is what happens thus i ask this question?

could someone please help me with this issue?
thanks
sunny

Comment: Why can't you wait until curl is finished?

Comment: Yes, i could do that but how do I find out when curl is finished and then proceed according. is there such a way? thanks

Comment: How do you run curl from your code?

Comment: I run it using AHK scripts. AHK script basically types the code onto the command prompt and then presses enter. There is no way to check whether the command has actually executed or not. So based on your advice, I have come up with a mod. I shall created a batch file of the curl command to run and  then execute this batch file from AHK as RunWait, batchfile. this would wait till the batch file complete which in turn means waiting till curl execution is complete. this would solve my problem. thanks for the help ShiDoiSi

Comment: I've submitted the same as an answer so that you can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code so that it waits until `curl` has completed. The exact way depends on what language you use.